# [php][curl] Problem with Curl - saving www

Tags: php, curl

I have this code and its work, but.. Its saving this wwww "to fast" and on html file i see in middle part of www Loading image :/ So how can i make to delay script or smth to stay little more time on this www and when all is loaded on www then saving it to file ?

```
<pre><?php

$file = fopen("brawl2.html", "w");
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, "https://brawlstats.com/club/8LG08L");
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FILE, $file);
curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
fclose($file);

?>
```

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 1):

Curl is not emulating a browser, it is just downloading a single file from the server, so it will never load these images.

In HTTP, a user agent (normally a browser, but in this case the `curl` library) sends a request for a particular resource (URL); then the server does whatever it needs to do, and then returns a response; and then you're done.

In your case, the server is responding with an HTML page that contains some JavaScript. When loaded by a browser, this JavaScript will run, and load the images; but `curl` is not a browser, so will not run this JavaScript.

There are libraries that do emulate a browser, which would be able to run this; they are referred to as "headless browsers", and a quick search turned up [this attempt at a comprehensive list](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers).

It's also worth remembering that even once the JavaScript is run, the images are probably not part of the HTML, but references to other files. If you don't save those, your saved HTML won't show any images if you unplug your internet, so you may also need to think about how to archive *all the resources needed to display the page*, not just the page itself.